Time zone conversion issue when calculating business days using BusinessHours class in Apex
I'm currently working on writing Apex code to calculate a date two business days from now, which takes into consideration time zones and using Salesforce's BusinessHours class (because we'd like to define holidays in Setup > Business Hours and take that into consideration when adding two business days from now). The goal is to use this as an invocable Apex in Flow. However, I'm encountering issues with the time zone conversion.
What I'm trying to achieve:

Convert the current user's time (which Salesforce stores internally
as GMT) into San Francisco (SF) time.
Add 2 business days to this SF time using the BusinessHours class.
Convert the resulting SF time back to GMT to store in Salesforce DateTime field.

The problem is that when I try to convert the user's time (stored as GMT) to SF time, the conversion doesn't seem to be happening correctly. The SF time is showing as identical to the GMT time, when it should be several hours behind (typically 7 or 8 hours, depending on daylight saving time).
private static final String SF_TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles';

@InvocableMethod(Label='Calculate Future Business Date' Description='Calculate date 2 business days from now in SF timezone.')
public static List<FutureBusinessDate> calculateFutureBusinessDate() {
    return calculateFutureBusinessDate(Datetime.now());
}

public static List<FutureBusinessDate> calculateFutureBusinessDate(Datetime currentTime) {
    List<FutureBusinessDate> results = new List<FutureBusinessDate>();
    BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = TRUE LIMIT 1];
    Id businessHoursId = bh.Id;

    // Current time is always in GMT (Salesforce stores date/time in GMT)
    Datetime gmtStartDate = currentTime;
    System.debug('GMT Start Date/Time: ' + gmtStartDate);

    // Convert GMT to SF time using ISO 8601 format
    String isoString = gmtStartDate.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
    Datetime sfStartDate = (Datetime)JSON.deserialize('"' + isoString + '"', Datetime.class);
    sfStartDate = sfStartDate.addSeconds(-TimeZone.getTimeZone(SF_TIMEZONE).getOffset(sfStartDate)/1000);
    System.debug('SF Start Date/Time: ' + sfStartDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', SF_TIMEZONE));

    // Calculate end date in SF time
    Long additionalMilliseconds = 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L; // 2 days in milliseconds
    Datetime sfEndDate = BusinessHours.add(businessHoursId, sfStartDate, additionalMilliseconds);
    System.debug('SF End Date/Time: ' + sfEndDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', SF_TIMEZONE));

    // Convert SF end time back to GMT
    String endIsoString = sfEndDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX', SF_TIMEZONE);
    Datetime gmtEndDate = (Datetime)JSON.deserialize('"' + endIsoString + '"', Datetime.class);
    System.debug('GMT End Date/Time: ' + gmtEndDate);

    FutureBusinessDate result = new FutureBusinessDate();
    result.gmtStartDate = gmtStartDate;
    result.gmtEndDate = gmtEndDate;
    result.sfStartDate = sfStartDate;
    result.sfEndDate = sfEndDate;
    results.add(result);

    return results;
}

public class FutureBusinessDate {
    @InvocableVariable
    public Datetime gmtStartDate;

    @InvocableVariable
    public Datetime gmtEndDate;

    @InvocableVariable
    public Datetime sfStartDate;

    @InvocableVariable
    public Datetime sfEndDate;
}

}
Here's the debug log I'm getting when running Anonymous Apex:
10:28:00:017 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|Current User TimeZone: America/New_York
10:28:00:018 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|Test Time in User Timezone: 2024-07-31 10:28:00
10:28:00:018 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|Test Time in New York: 2024-07-31 10:28:00
10:28:00:018 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|Test Time in GMT: 2024-07-31 14:28:00
10:28:00:029 USER_DEBUG [101]|DEBUG|GMT Start Date/Time: 2024-07-31 14:28:00
10:28:00:030 USER_DEBUG [107]|DEBUG|SF Start Date/Time: 2024-07-31 14:28:00
10:28:00:032 USER_DEBUG [112]|DEBUG|SF End Date/Time: 2024-08-05 14:28:00
10:28:00:032 USER_DEBUG [117]|DEBUG|GMT End Date/Time: 2024-08-05 14:28:00
10:28:00:032 USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|GMT Start Date/Time: 2024-07-31 14:28:00
10:28:00:032 USER_DEBUG [17]|DEBUG|GMT End Date/Time: 2024-08-05 14:28:00
10:28:00:032 USER_DEBUG [18]|DEBUG|SF Start Date/Time: 2024-07-31 14:28:00
10:28:00:032 USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|SF End Date/Time: 2024-08-05 14:28:00
10:28:00:032 USER_DEBUG [20]|DEBUG|User Start Date/Time: 2024-07-31 10:28:00
10:28:00:033 USER_DEBUG [21]|DEBUG|User End Date/Time: 2024-08-05 10:28:00
10:28:00:033 USER_DEBUG [25]|DEBUG|SF Timezone offset for start: -7 hours
10:28:00:033 USER_DEBUG [26]|DEBUG|SF Timezone offset for end: -7 hours

As you can see, the GMT and SF times are identical (14:28:00), which is incorrect. The SF time should be 7 hours behind GMT (07:28:00). I've tried various approaches, including using TimeZone.getOffset() and ISO 8601 formatting with JSON deserialization, but the issue persists.
Would anyone happen to know or have an inkling what's going on, and what I can do to troubleshoot this better?
Thank you!

DateTime dt = ...; System.debug(dt) prints the stringified date/time in the running user's  timezone.

Relying on System.debug's information isn't ideal, as pointed by @identigral. By the way, did you consider doing what this answer (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/238891/18269) suggests?

@identigral Great catch with the system.debug; I'll try and see what the values are when I call this class from a Flow.

@RenatoOliveira I hadn't seen that post actually, I'll give that a shot. Thanks for pointing me to it!
